# Как интерпретировать ROC AUC для вероятностей в бинарной классификации?

Tags: машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Задача предсказания класса (0 или 1). Решаю с помощью логистической регрессии. На выходе, по условиям задачи, просят предоставить вероятность того, что объект относится к классу 1. Известно, что в задаче используется метрика «ROC AUC». На сколько мне известно, метрика рассчитывается на основе нормированного количества истинноположительных и ложноположительных  *объектов* (TPR, FPR). Но у нас просят вероятности!

Подскажите, как интерпретировать вероятности «ROC AUC»–метрике для бинарной классификации?

Comment: Вы можете уточнить суть вопроса? В чем вы видите противоречия? В логистической регрессии используется сигмоид, значения которого можно рассматривать как вероятность принадлежности "позитивному"  классу. При округлении данной вероятности получаем `0` или `1`.

Comment: @MaxU В этом  и весь вопрос: действительно ли мы просто округляем значение (пусть даже, к примеру, и с порогом) или же все–таки есть какая–то иная интерпретация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В логистической регрессии используется [сигмоида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0), значения которой являются вероятностью принадлежности к "позитивному" классу и лежит в диапазоне `(0, 1)`. При округлении данной вероятности получаем `0` или `1`. Для принятия окончательгоно решения (о принадлежности к классу) применяют обычное округление:

если `вероятность < 0.5` - округляем до `0`

если `вероятность >= 0.5` - округляем до `1`

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос бы в том, просто ли это округление или позади что–то хитрое. Потому что если просо округление, не ясно, зачем авторы задачи просят выдавать вероятность принадлежности к классу, а не сам класс.